# Docker containers not running on VM

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am new to Docker and I am following the 'Getting Started' documentation at the Docker site.

I am trying to run 3 containers on a VM.
OS: Centos 7.3
Docker: 17.03.1-ce

I followed the first part and could get hello-world running on a container inside the VM.

Then I moved on to the Docker compose example.
I have the following directory structure:

```
home
 |
  - docker-compose.yml
 |
  - docker-test
     |
      - app.py
      - Dockerfile
      - requirements.txt
```

The files under docker-test are from the python app example on the docker website.

With the docker-compose, I was attempting to run 3 containers of the hello-world example.

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
 web:
  image: hello-world
  deploy:
   replicas: 3
   resources:
    limits:
      cpus: "0.1"
      memory: 50M
   restart_policy:
    condition: on-failure
 ports:
  - "80:80"
 networks:
  - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

Then I ran the following commands:

```
sudo docker swarm init
sudo docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml getstartedlab

sudo docker stack ps getstartedlab shows:    
ID            NAME                 IMAGE               NODE              DESIRED STATE  CURRENT STATE            ERROR  PORTS    
iytr4ptz3m8l  getstartedlab_web.1  hello-world:latest  <node1>  Shutdown       Complete 16 minutes ago         
s5t41txo05ex  getstartedlab_web.2  hello-world:latest  <node2>  Shutdown       Complete 16 minutes ago         
91iitdnc49fk  getstartedlab_web.3  hello-world:latest  <node3>  Shutdown       Complete 16 minutes ago
```

However, 
sudo docker ps shows no containers and when I curl http://localhost:80, it can't connect.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Your `docker-compose.yml` file says that the `web` service should use the `hello-world` image, which just prints a message & exits when run, leading to all of the containers being stopped.  Presumably, you meant to instead use the image created by building `docker-test/`; to do this, simply replace the `image: hello-world` line with `build: docker-test`.

Comment: So I did that:cat docker-compose.yml 
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build: docker-test
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    . . .
and when I do sudo docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml getstartedlab
it errors out:
Ignoring unsupported options: build

Creating network getstartedlab_webnet
Creating service getstartedlab_web
Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = 3 desc = ContainerSpec: image reference must be provided